# Opportunity object access when a record triggered flow is triggered by action of a platform licensed user

Tags: salesforce

I have a salesforce flow created on a custom object P, P is managed package custom object and child object of Opportunity.

There is another managed custom object B, B is child of P and also of Opportunity.

Now there is a record triggered flow which gets triggered on record creation of B, it reads parent of B -> P and from P it goes  (B -> P -> Opportunity -> Custom field). I was expecting this flow to fail as it tries to read Opportunity custom field and record triggered flow was triggered by platform user which doesn't have access to Opportunity object

but this flow works fine.
It is confusing. I understand that record triggered flow runs as system user and don't respect FLS but i was expecting it to be not able to read opportunity field.